# Is it legal to cast a struct to an array?

Tags: rust, slice, unsafe, memory-layout, object-model

Consider the following:

```rust
// Just a sequence of adjacent fields of same the type
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S<T> {
    a : T,
    b : T,
    c : T,
    d : T,
}

impl<T : Sized> S<T> {
    fn new(a : T, b : T, c : T, d : T) -> Self {
        Self {
            a,
            b,
            c,
            d,
        }
    }
    // reinterpret it as an array
    fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T] {
        unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(self as *const Self as *const T, 4) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S::new(1, 2, 3, 4);
    
    let a = s.as_slice();
    
    println!("s :: {:?}\n\
              a :: {:?}", s, a);
}
```

- Is this code portable?
- Is it always safe to assume a repr(C) struct with fields of same type can be reinterpreted like an array? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is safe and portable, except for very large `T` (fix below). None of the points listed in the safety section of the documentation for [std::slice::from_raw_parts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) are a concern here:

- The data pointer is valid for `mem::size_of::<T>() * 4`, which is the size of `S<T>`, and is properly aligned.

  - All of the items are in the same allocation object, because they are in the same struct.
  - The pointer is not null, because it is a cast from the safe `&self` parameter, and it is properly aligned, because `S<T>` has (at least) the alignment of `T`.
- The data parameter definitely points to 4 consecutive initialized `T`s, because `S` is marked `#[repr(C)]` which [is defined such that](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#reprc-structs) in your struct, no padding would be introduced. (`repr(Rust)` makes no such guarantee).
- The memory referenced is not mutated during the lifetime of the reference, which is guaranteed by the borrow checker.
- The total size of the slice must not be greater than `isize::MAX`. The code does not check this, so it is technically a safety hole. To be sure, add a check to `as_slice`, before the `unsafe`:

  ```
  assert!(std::mem::size_of::<S<T>>() <= isize::MAX as _);
  ```

  The check will normally be optimized out.

Comment: So it is also guaranteed there will be no padding between fields?

Comment: @Nazinho No, `repr(c)` does not remove padding. It pads the struct the same way `C` does. If you want to remove the padding, you can use `repr(packed)`. https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html

Comment: The packing of elements in a standard Rust [array](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/arrays-and-slices.html) is the same as fields in a [`repr(C)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-layout.html#the-c-representation) struct (size rounded up to next multiple of alignment)

Comment: "_It pads the struct the same way C does._" Note that the C Standard does not specify padding, but leaves that an implementation detail. It _does_ specify that there is no internal padding in arrays.

Comment: @ex nihilo OTOH Rust says that *stride >= size* for arrays

Comment: @Nazinho [This part of the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#reprc-structs) says that in fact, there is no padding between the fields in your case.

Comment: Is there a canonical way to go from owned struct to owned fixed-size array, i.e. how would you define `fn from(s: S) -> [T; 4]`? Is `std::mem::transmute` the right tool for the job in that case?