# Is it possible to access elements of a struct using pointers in Rust?

Tags: c, struct, rust

In C, we can access individual elements of a struct via pointers. How do we do the same in Rust?

The code below shows how to access elements using pointers in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} Data;

Data* new_data(const int a, const int b, const int c) {
     Data* data = malloc(sizeof(Data));
     data->a = a;
     data->b = b;
     data->c = c;
     return data;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Data* data = new_data(23, 35, 12);

    // accessing elements via pointers
    printf("\n --- Using pointers ---\n");
    printf("a: %d\n", *((int*)data + 0));
    printf("b: %d\n", *((int*)data + 1));
    printf("c: %d\n", *((int*)data + 2));

    // using pointer magic
    printf("\n --- Using pointer magic ---\n");
    printf("b: %d\n", *((int*)((char*)data + sizeof(int))));
    printf("c: %d\n", *((int*)((char*)data + sizeof(int) * 2)));

    // accessing elements via name
    printf("\n --- Using names ---\n");
    printf("a: %d\n", data->a);
    printf("b: %d\n", data->b);
    printf("c: %d\n", data->c);

    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

The above is compiled using `gcc` and I'm aware it's also platform specific, but it's not my concern.

The below is what I currently have in Rust.

```
struct Data<T> {
    el: Vec<T>
}

impl <T> Data<T> where T: Copy {
    fn new(a: T, b: T, c: T) -> Self {
        let mut s = Self { el: Vec::with_capacity(3) };
        s.el.push(a);
        s.el.push(b);
        s.el.push(c);
        return s;
    }

    fn get_a(&self) -> T { self.el[0] }
    fn get_b(&self) -> T { self.el[1] }
    fn get_c(&self) -> T { self.el[2] }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data::new(23, 35, 12);
    println!("data capacity: {:?}", data.el.capacity());

    println!("a: {:?}", data.get_a());
    println!("b: {:?}", data.get_b());
    println!("c: {:?}", data.get_c());
}
```

I'd like to be able to use

```
struct Data<T> {
    a: T,
    b: T,
    c: T
}
```

and access each element via their index.

Comment: The first one you're doing in C is not strictly legal - in C.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get pointer offset in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310483/how-to-get-pointer-offset-in-bytes)

Comment: Also see [How to get a pointer to a containing struct from a pointer to a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38819569/3650362). For the C version, see [Get pointer to object from pointer to some member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33870219/3650362).

Comment: I just noticed `__attribute__((packed))`. AFAIK even in C you cannot get a usable `int*` to a member of a `packed` struct, because they are not guaranteed to be aligned. Technically I believe it is OK here because `malloc` returns a pointer with the maximum alignment, but Rust's system allocator has no such guarantee (and doing it on a stack variable would be wrong in either language).

Comment: @trentcl. I'm currently reading about [layouts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html)
I've had a quick look at some of the links you've posted but I'll need time to digest them.

Comment: Here are some other options you might consider, depending on what you don't like about what you currently have: [1](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ad939dd7d5ecafad880c0c9714edf66), [2](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=47fe799a048abbc23ddafd8814812501), and [3](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b40721156f07d4bff8b499ba4b49e25d)

Comment: @trentcl The third one seems to be the closest to what I'm looking for. Would it be compatible with [avx](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/simd-for-faster-computing.html)?

Comment: Actually, I think the 3rd one is enough to answer this question since it uses raw pointers and it allows access to elements by indexing. Don't worry about the avx compatiblity - that should be my homework. Can you post it so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In the general case, there is no way to do this correctly in Rust today.** However, your particular struct avoids some of the worst problems, making it safe to borrow the entire struct as a borrowed slice (`&[T]`). To do so you need to do three things:

1. Mark the struct `repr(C)`, **but not `repr(packed)`**! Packed structs are unaligned, and references must always be properly aligned.
2. Check that the size of the struct is no larger than `isize::MAX`.
3. Use [`slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) to borrow a `&[T]` from the `&Data<T>`.

For a point-by-point justification of why this is sound, see [Is it legal to cast a struct to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240126/is-it-legal-to-cast-a-struct-to-an-array)

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Data<T> {
    pub a: T,
    pub b: T,
    pub c: T,
}

impl<T> Data<T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    fn new(a: T, b: T, c: T) -> Self {
        Data { a, b, c }
    }

    // N.B. you could also implement `AsRef<[T]>` and/or `Borrow<[T]>`, which
    // are used frequently in generic code
    fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T] {
        assert!(std::mem::size_of::<Self>() <= isize::MAX as _);
        // This `unsafe` block was copied from Stack Overflow without proving
        // its use is correct in this context, so it's almost certainly wrong
        unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(self as *const _ as *const T, 3) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test function to add confidence that casting to a slice works.

```
unsafe fn test_slice_data_equiv<T: Clone>(t: &T) {
    let data = Data { a: t.clone(), b: t.clone(), c: t.clone() };
    let slice: [T; 3] = [ t.clone(), t.clone(), t.clone()];
    fn as_u8_ptr<U>(r: &U) -> * const u8 {
        r as * const U as * const u8
    }
    let data_ptr = as_u8_ptr(&data);
    let slice_ptr = as_u8_ptr(&slice);
    
    assert_eq!(as_u8_ptr(&data.a).offset_from(data_ptr),
               as_u8_ptr(&slice[0]).offset_from(slice_ptr),
               "Data.a != slice[0]");
    assert_eq!(as_u8_ptr(&data.b).offset_from(data_ptr),
               as_u8_ptr(&slice[1]).offset_from(slice_ptr),
               "Data.b != slice[1]");
    assert_eq!(as_u8_ptr(&data.c).offset_from(data_ptr),
               as_u8_ptr(&slice[2]).offset_from(slice_ptr),
               "Data.c != slice[2]");
}

#[test]
fn test_some_offsets() {
    unsafe {
        test_slice_data_equiv(&0_u32);
        test_slice_data_equiv(&0_u64);
    }
}
```

Comment: That way only looks nice on the surface but uses `match`. I'm looking for ways to use pointers so that data could be used by some `simd` libraries, while also being able to access elements by name. If you're interested, here are some links of what I'm looking into; [1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.26.0/std/arch/index.html), [2](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=100,106&techs=AVX2).

Comment: Ok, you wanted to access the elements as a slice.  I was confused by "access each element via their index".